# Plotly python histogram add custom colors to distinct values

Tags: python, plotly, histogram, visualization

I have a dataframe, with 4 distinct values in a column, for each value I need to set the custom colors.

Below is the sample data

```
val,cluster
118910.000000,3
71209.000000,2
25674.666667,0
109267.666667,3
8.000000,1
```

Below is the code.

```
fig = px.histogram(types, x="val",color='cluster')
fig.show()
```

types is the dataframe name from data given

When I figureI get default colors. Instead I need to get

0:red

2:blue

1:purple

3:green

How can I set the custom colors in python plotly for histogram

Can anyone help on this pls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`color_discrete_map`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.histogram.html#plotly.express.histogram).

```
import pandas as pd 
import random
df = pd.DataFrame([[random.random()*100,random.randint(0,3)]for i in range (100)],columns = ['val','cluster'])
fig = px.histogram(df, x="cluster",y='val',
                   color = 'cluster',
                    color_discrete_map = {0:'red',1:'blue',2:'purple',3:'green'}
                  )
fig
```

[image]